# Google Maps API (static) - custom marker not showing up

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&markers=icon:http://tinyurl.com/2ftvtt6&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here.

Developer Guide:

[API - Custom Icons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons)

...markers=icon:**url**[stop]&zoom=...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that you defined marker style, but didn't define marker location. It should be:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&markers=icon:http://tinyurl.com/2ftvtt6|40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false

Answer (score 10):

I had some problems with the markers, too.

Maybe these hints help other guys

- Marker should be max 64x64 pixels in size
- long marker filenames can cause issues
- always define a marker location - see accepted answer

Comment: this was actually my problem, marker was 100x100, so, just resize marker and don't forget marker location on the map. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, this fix my issue!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another point I wanted to add for future reference. Don't use ***svg*** files. They won't be rendered in the final map image.