# Add marker to center of static google map

Tags: google-maps

It is very simple to create a google map and center on a given location (see below).  It is also similarity simple to create a google map and show markers on it by doing something like `markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211%7C11206%7C11222`.

How would I just create a simple centered map like the below, but add a single marker in the very center?  Thanks

```
<img alt="Map" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=+AUBURN+WA+98001&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=400x400&amp;sensor=false">
```

Comment: Have you already read this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers

Comment: @Dr.Molle.  Yes I have.  It describes adding markers, but not at the center.  I suppose I can create a map which specifies the center as I did in my example, and then create a marker with the exact same address, however, I expect there is a more efficient way to do it all at once with one call to google's database (or however they do it)

Comment: [This](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7CWilliamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&sensor=false) works for me (and should work according to the documentation).

Comment: It is close to centered, but isn't.  Probably good enough.  Only way I can center is do the following:  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:blue|label:S|Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&sensor=false&center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY

Comment: see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180006/google-maps-api-static-custom-marker-not-showing-up

Answer (score 7):

I guess that the map automatically will fit to show the specified markers, 
[here you will find](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#MarkerLocations)

> Marker Locations
>
> Each marker descriptor must contain a set of one or more locations
>   defining where to place the marker on the map. These locations may be
>   either specified as latitude/longitude values or as addresses. These
>   locations are separated using the pipe character (|).
>
> The location parameters define the marker's location on the map. If
>   the location is off the map, that marker will not appear in the
>   constructed image provided that center and zoom parameters are
>   supplied. However, if these parameters are not supplied, the Static
>   Map server will automatically construct an image which contains the
>   supplied markers. (See Implicit Positioning below.)

Comment: indeed it works :), check this out : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=5&size=250x250&sensor=false&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red|39.926586,116.405640

Comment: ^^ Thanks for the above example @Victor! Very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also add your own centered background image ontop if the map :)

```
background: url('yourmarker.png' ) center no-repeat, url(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=AUBURN+WA+98001&zoom=14&amp&size=400x400);
```

Answer (score 1):

here i am giving the code in step by step

```
NSString *strLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_message.latitude];
NSString *strLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_message.longitude];
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@center=%@,%@&zoom=15&size=200x200&markers=color:red%%7Clabel:C%%7C%@,%@&key=%@",https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?,strLat,strLong,strLat,strLong,GOOGLE_API_BROWSER_KEY];
NSLog(@"strURL %@",strURL);
strURL = [strURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%%" withString:@"%"];
```

now you have a image url

Comment: Thank you dude. Just giving `center` without any value does the job

Answer (score 0):

Google Static Maps Reference For Addresses:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Addresses

Here's a JavaScript function that I've used recently to do this. The addressElements parameter passed to the function is an array of address elements e.g. `['10 Main St', 'Brownsville', 'MS', '27123', 'USA']`.

You can see that I've commented out the center and zoom properties as you don't need those when you define a marker. To remove the marker, just uncomment those two lines and comment out the markers line.

You can obviously construct this image yourself, but I used the URLSearchParams to simplify parameter creation and have them URL encoded automagically.

```
function getGoogleMapsImage(addressElements) {
    var image = Nucleus.element('img');
    image.width = '256';
    image.height = '256';
    var joined = addressElements.join(',');
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    //params.append('center', joined);
    //params.append('zoom', '15');
    params.append('size', '256x256');
    params.append('maptype', 'roadmap');
    params.append('key', 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE');
    params.append('markers', 'color:red|label:C|' + joined);
    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?' + params.toString();
    image.src = url;
    return image;
}
```