# Google Static Map API - custom marker not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have marker location defined (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180006/google-maps-api-static-custom-marker-not-showing-up) example), the API returns the map w/out error, but the marker does not show up. I am puzzled and eager to have some pointers.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.697423,150.564022&zoom=8&size=600x600&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6%257C-30.697423,150.564022&sensor=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should replace `%257C` with `|`, here is a proper link:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.697423,150.564022&zoom=8&size=600x600&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6|-30.697423,150.564022&sensor=false

Comment: wow - that is indeed working, yet my understanding is that it's not what the [API doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1#CustomIcons) says. thanks though!!!